# Change function call to another function call in arm using IDA

Tags: ida, arm

Is it possible to patch arm lib in a way that changes branch instruction calling one function to another function call?

I have instruction

```
B function_a
```

and want change it to:

```
B function_b
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737035/can-someone-explain-the-branch-opcode-in-arm) for details on how branch instructions are encoded on ARM. Here's what you should do:

1. Set `Options->General->Number of opcode bytes` to 4 (if it was 0 initially)
2. Find any `B` instruction.
3. Just to make sure you understand it, work out the displacement from `pc+8` at the `B` instruction to the destination, and verify that the displacement in the instruction matches what you expect.
4. Calculate the displacement to the target to which you wish to branch instead.
5. Use `Edit->Patch program->Change byte` to modify the current instruction. IDA will update the display, so you can tell whether you've succeeded or not. If you haven't, keep messing with it until you get the bytes you want.
6. To generate a patch file, you can use `File->Produce file->Create .DIF file`.